# Pull headers from a list and create a DataFrame with headers side-by-side to list elements

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

After scraping a website, I ended up with a list which looks like this:

```
data = ['\xa0header1', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3', '\xa0header2', 'element4', 'element5']
```

and so on.

I want to create a panda dataframe with the data I scraped that looks like this:

```
          A         B
   0  element1   header1
   1  element2   header1
   2  element3   header1
   3  element4   header2
   4  element5   header2
```

So, basically, I want to show in the next column the header which is above a group of elements of the initial list.

How can it be done, considering the special character in front of the headers makes it easy to look them up in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### itertools groupby + repeat + chain

This is one solution using the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module. In essence these are the only operations we need to undertake:

1. **Group** items according to whether they start with `\xa0`.
2. **Repeat** headers for each list within your list of lists after grouping.
3. **Chain** results for series `A` and `B` to remove nested lists.

Crucially, these operations are already implemented lazily and efficiently in the standard library, so there's no need to reproduce in pure Python (although this, in itself, is a good learning exercise).

Complete solution:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby, repeat

chainer = chain.from_iterable

data = ['\xa0header1', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3',
        '\xa0header2', 'element4', 'element5']

def condition(x):
    return x.startswith('\xa0')

# create list of lists for elements
elements = [list(j) for i, j in groupby(data, key=condition) if not i]

# create list of headers
headers = [next(j) for i, j in groupby(data, key=condition) if i]

# chain list of lists, and use repeat for headers
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(chainer(LoL)),
                   'B': list(chainer(repeat(i, j) for i, j in \
                             zip(headers, map(len, elements))))})

print(df)

          A         B
0  element1   header1
1  element2   header1
2  element3   header1
3  element4   header2
4  element5   header2
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. However, maybe I was not clear enough but the headers actually include words like \xa0Eggs or \xa0Plates for example that I want to extract and put in the next colmun instead of enumerating.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use `collections.defaultdict` to create a dictionary mapping headers to elements. Potentially more intuitive than `itertools.groupby` and requires only one pass.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain, repeat

chainer = chain.from_iterable

data = ['\xa0header1', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3',
        '\xa0header2', 'element4', 'element5']

# create dictionary of lists
# each key a separate header; values are list of elements
d = defaultdict(list)

for item in data:
    if item.startswith('\xa0'):
        key = item.strip()
    else:
        d[key].append(item)

# chain list of lists, and use repeat for headers
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(chainer(d.values())),
                   'B': list(chainer(repeat(i, j) for i, j in \
                             zip(d.keys(), map(len, d.values()))))})

print(df)

          A        B
0  element1  header1
1  element2  header1
2  element3  header1
3  element4  header2
4  element5  header2
```